# davfs2 unable to create files, no problem creating directoies

Tags: permissions, mount, webdav

[SOLVED] I have a very strange behavior connecting to our compnay using webdav.
I use davfs2:

```
SB_PARAMS=uid=igeeks,gid=igeeks,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=666,users,rw
mount -t davfs <SERVER-URI> <MOUNT-POINT> --verbose -o ${SB_PARAMS}
```

Now I can connect to the remote directory as I want.

... except from ONE SINGLE LAPTOP ...

I can connect the same way, I see all files and directories, I can read all files and create and delete directories; and I can delete files.

Except, when I want **to create a file** I get "**permission denied**".
The parent directory has the following flags:

```
drwxrwxrwx
```

should not be a problem, though.

The credentials are on all my machines in /etc/davfs2/secrets.

The mount command shows the following:

```
https://webdav.mycompnay.ch/webdav on /mnt/bbw/webdav type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1001,allow_other,max_read=16384,uid=1000,gid=1001,helper=davfs)
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED]

I have forgotten to add the following two lines in `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf`:

```
dav_group users
use_locks 0
```

Now, it works perfectly.